# How to get text of the Button and compare it with some string?

Tags: android-studio

I want to compare text of the Button with some string.First of all, how to get this text of the Button. And how to use equals method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would assume you want to get the text of a button using android studio for apps? If so see the following:

```
Button b = (Button)v;
String buttonText = b.getText().toString();
if (buttonText == text){
    //something here
}
```

-Or-

```
Button b = (Button)v;
if(b.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(text)){
    //something here
}
```

Comment: Do not use `==` to compare Strings